# Symfony2 downgrade bundle to use php 5.6.20

Tags: php, symfony, version, downgrade

I have a problem with some bundle, i use bundle: vich/uploader-bundle 1.0.1

so my project run only on PHP 7.0 ... how to downgrade some bundle to use PHP 5.6.20 ?

composer install:

Problem 1

- Installation request for ocramius/package-versions 1.0.4 -> satisfiable by ocramius/package-versions[1.0.4].
- ocramius/package-versions 1.0.4 requires php ~7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.20) does not satisfy that requirement.

Problem 2

- Installation request for ocramius/proxy-manager 2.0.1 -> satisfiable by ocramius/proxy-manager[2.0.1].
- ocramius/proxy-manager 2.0.1 requires php ~7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.20) does not satisfy that requirement.

Problem 3

- ocramius/proxy-manager 2.0.1 requires php ~7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
- vich/uploader-bundle 1.0.1 requires ocramius/proxy-manager ~1.0|~2.0 -> satisfiable by ocramius/proxy-manager[2.0.1].
- Installation request for vich/uploader-bundle 1.0.1 -> satisfiable by vich/uploader-bundle[1.0.1].

Comment: Did you gave a try to this setting ?

Answer (score 5):

In your composer file add the PHP version `config` key like this:

```
"config": {
    "platform": {
        "php": "5.6"
    }
},
```